# Combining DWORD Values

Tags: group-policy, activex, axis

I'm trying to permit automatic silent install of some internal ActiveX controls using AXIS, as per [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631688(v=ws.10).aspx). In the article, it states that you can define how HTTPS exceptions are handled, for example, 0 means that all checks must be passed. It then provides four excpetions that you can allow, using the following values:

```
0x0000100
0x0001000
0x0002000
0x0000200
```

It then states that you can combine them. The latter two, for example are to ignore date errors on the certificate and ignore improper certificate usage. To ignore both, use the value 0x0002200.

What if I want to ignore all four? Can I use 0x0003300? Or am I oversimplifying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked to says, immediately below those values:

> To implement multiple exceptions, add the appropriate DWORD value for the desired exception(s) to form a cumulative value.

(In actuality, since it's a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), you bitwise OR the values together, but arithmetic addition gives you the same result here.)

Comment: Thanks - so in simple terms my example would work?

Comment: Is "yes" a simple enough term for you? :)